# Convert mws file to text without Maple

Tags: file, file-conversion, maple

I would like to see the code of some mws files (made in Maple) but I don't have Maple installed on my computer. 
Is it possible to convert a mws file to a text file or open it without Maple?

Answer (score 2):

You could download and install the free [Maple Player](https://www.maplesoft.com/products/maple/Mapleplayer/), which should be able to open a .mws file and display its contents.

[edit] The older .mws format Maple file would have its input code lines displayed in plaintext red, and which could even be cut&pasted from the Player, I believe.